# Android SQLite и перевод приложения на другой язык

Tags: android, sqlite

В  моем приложении много текста и другой информации, которую я хочу хранить в базе данных, но у меня возник вопрос, можно ли как-то реализовать     создание базы данных в зависимости от языка, который выбран на устройстве? Например с ресурсами string.xml так делать можно, а как сделать тоже самое с базой данных(я понимаю, что база данных с другим языком должна быть создана, мне не понятно, как  создать нужную  бд ) ?. Спасибо.

Comment: можете при открытии\проверке существования\создании базы в имени файла базы использовать название локали, например `EN-myDatabase.sqlite`, `RU-myDatabase.sqlite`

Comment: Можно немного подробнее, либо где-то почитать об этом? Буду признателен.

Comment: База данных хранится в файле. У фаыла есть имя. Вы можете в имени файла использовать приставку с названием локали.